# Unreal Conditionals

Tags: conditionals

*If you want to use the inclined plane to help you move an object (and who wouldn’t?), then you have to move the object over a longer distance to get to the desired height than **if you had started from directly below and moved upward**. This is probably already clear to you from a lifetime of stair climbing.*

Q1. I was wondering the whether the part **"if you had started ~ and moved upward"** is a hypothetical expressing an imagined situation.

Q2. If the **"if you had ~ upward"** part was indeed used as a hypothetical, then why would the author use the past perfect **"had started"** instead of past simple such as **"started"**. If author had intended to make a comparison between what is the more "common" way of utilizing the inclined plane versus somewhat an inefficient way of using the plane, I think he could have just used the past simple to denote the unreal aspect of starting from directly below and move upward.

Comment: *Were* it not contrafactual (hypothetical), it would have been the simple past. HTH.

Comment: But can't the use of the simple past still denote the counterfactualness of the statement?

Comment: The change in tense helps signal the counterfactuality.

Comment: @Kris So you mean just using the past simple would not be sufficient for signalling counterfactuality. But aren't there cases where the use of past simple can indeed express the counterfactuality? such as in "She would be happy if I had a car."

Comment: What **else** could *had* be? I'm not sure.

Comment: The past perfect construction is there to identify the starting point as being earlier than the other past time event in the sentence -- the one referenced by the VP _move the object_. The point is that one occurs (hypothetically) before the other (equally hypothetical) event in the description.

Comment: @John Lawler So "had started" as well as "moved" were both used as a hypothetical in comparison with "move the object over a longer distance ~ desired height." and "had started" precedes "moved" in terms of timing. I'm just trying to make sense of this because one student I teach was very eager to know the reasoning behind this sentence. Thank you all for your thoughtful insights!